# Rosewill RAID Enclosure - Adding a Second Card

Tags: linux, raid

I have a couple of [Rosewill RSV-S5](http://www.rosewill.com/products/1188/productDetail.htm) RAID enclosures.  Each one comes with a PCI express card to act as the RAID host.  However, on my host system (Slackware 13.1.0 running Linux 2.6.33.4) I'm just using software RAID as the controller, so the card simply handles the SATA port replication to connect all 5 drives in each enclosure to the host.

Since each card has two ports on it, I've only been using one of the two cards to connect both of my enclosures.  Now I'm trying to add a third enclosure to the second card and the host system doesn't seem to be recognizing it.  I'm not sure what to look for other than `/proc/filesystems`, which doesn't show the new drive (which would be `/dev/sdl`).

Can anybody think of what might be wrong here?  Additional things I can check?

(p.s. Apologies to the person who commented the first time I asked about this a few days ago.  I had my symptoms mistaken and ran some more tests to straighten it out.  Thank you.)